# Reading Cached Image File in Android and getting Null from BitmapFactory.decode

Tags: android

I am trying to get an image taken from the camera, and storing it locally in a cache to preview in an **ImageView** and upload to a server when needed. The bitmap that I get back is null.

Below is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                // TODO - save the full sized image as well
                if(mCurrentPhotoPath!=null){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image File found!");

                    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    if (imageBitmap !=null){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Successfully retrieved image back.");
                    }
                    ImageView postImageView= (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.post_image);

                    postImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageCache(Context context) throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = context.getCacheDir();

        Log.i(TAG, "StorageDir: "+storageDir);

        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Searching around one of the solutions that I found and tried was setting the BitmapFactory.Options, but it didn't work for my case.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

Edit: Ran **getActivity().getCacheDir().list()** and found that the files are indeed saved. Also, here is the button that saves the images:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())!=null){
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageCache(getActivity());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.i(TAG, "Error Creating File!!! No Space??");
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please check your camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "No camera to run");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and found that the files are indeed saved`. Just a list() will not prove that. You created the files yourself so they were there already with length 0. What is the length in bytes afterwards? I think still 0. getCacheDir() delivers internal private memory unreachable for the external picture taker. Try with `getExternalCacheDir()` instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, that worked like a charm! Didn't know there was a difference in the cache dirs.